# Proving a function is Lipschitz is symmetrical

Tags: calculus

When we want to prove that a function is Lipschitz, we want to prove $|f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|$. But we could just prove $f(x)-f(y)\le L|x-y|$ right? The problem is kind of symmetrical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you show $f(x)-f(y) \leq L|x-y|$ is true for all $x$ and $y$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$. $f(x)-f(y) \leq L|x-y|$ implies $f(y)-f(x) \leq L|y-x| = L|x-y|$. One of $f(x)-f(y)$ and $f(y)-f(x)$ is equal to $|f(x)-f(y)|$, so $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y|$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps to understand what we're trying to say here. What we really mean when we say a function is lipschitz is that the distance between two points of the function is a constant times the distance between the points. In a sense, the distance between points of the function depends linearly on the distance of the points themselves. For instance, a linear function is like this. Let $f(x) = ax$ for a positive real number $a$. Try to show that $f$ is Lipschitz. What is $L$ here?